# Offline accessible RSS feed with images

Tags: android, database, parsing, rss

I'm new to android since a short period and after looking around on different forums (including this one) i couldn't really make up what the best way would be of parsing my RSS feed.

Here's my problem: 
I'm creating an application that is to be used on the north and south pole. Places with basicly no connection.
I will be putting available a dictionary of all the animal life on both these poles.
The point of the application is that it has to be able to be synchronized when back on the mainland. (Because this dictionary keeps growing and changing)
The information will be put available trough an online RSS feed.

Now my question is, what is the best (and possebly easiest) way of doing this?
[This is how the RSS feed will be build up](http://beta.npolar.no/no/om-oss/nyheter/newsfeed.xml)

I have a few years knowledge of Java programming (Worked with netbeans), Now i'm using Eclipse. I already managed to create a local database with the columns i need to store the information in (SQLite). Now my next challenge is how to bring the content from the web to this local database (including the enclosured image if possible)

Hope someone can help me with this problem. In the meantime i'll be browsing further in search of an anwser.

Awaiting your reply

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android

If that ship hasn't sailed yet get them to publish the data as a JSON string.  Takes only ~30 lines of code to grab the string and populate a Java data object with it.